# "Visual not text code" question closing issue

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This QA was, IMO, unfortunately closed :

[How to design vertical UI layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324203/how-to-design-vertical-ui-layout/51324308)

As I mention there

> "This question absolutely and utterly has a totally clear problem statement, an exact, specific example, and precise description of the exact problem. I don't think I've seen a better question from a "newbie". Incredibly disappointing it was closed."

Something I was thinking - when working with the subtle and difficult iOS autolayout system, it's a graphical IDE. (It's extremely difficult and there are a thousand fantastic questions about the subtleties of it on this site, but you don't generally have "text code", it's done graphically.)

Regarding why this was mysteriously closed, I'm guessing folks looking at it briefly, thought **"oh there's no *text code there*"** and hence voted to closing it without understanding the situation.

(Note that the close reason .. "Questions seeking debugging help..." has no connection to anything at all.  The person is not seeking "debugging help", they're asking an astute question about a sophisticated issue.)  (Surely the fact that the person is not a native English writer is not relevant.)

Thoughts?

Best thing to "do" if you see a Q like this that one feels should not have ben closed?  (Other than the useless reopen button! :)  )

As I mention it's a shame as it's a new chum on the site who could be a useful member.

Comment: **1.** I doubt people are closing the question because the OP isn't a native English writer but rather because of the confusion that is being caused in their writing due to errors / lack of proofreading. **2.** I have edited the question to the best of my ability to make it clearer, however, in certain places even I wasn't sure what the OP was trying to say as a result someone glancing over the question can be forgiven for a mistake they might make trying to understand the OP.

Comment: it was kind of you to edit, good one

Comment: The more I read this question, the cynic in me can't help but feel that some of the wording has been chosen intentionally with the current "unwelcoming" debacle in mind.

Comment: lol true @Script47 - it's a perfect example.  (1) people who know utterly nothing about IOS are voting to close because, **on a glance, there's no 'code samples'** (2) bluntly (look at the other answer here) "sophisticated" writers prefer, let's face it, native English writing.

Comment: I mean the question just couldn't be clearer, it's exactly the sort of thing other experts at work ask for my advice on how to solve certain autolayout problems.  Anyway.

Comment: I have no knowledge regarding iOS and I stay in my lane (read tags), however, if a question like that popped up in the tags I use, I would've voted to close it too, namely for being unclear or too broad. What I mean't by my cynic comment above is that you seem to want to focus on the native writing aspect instead of the flaws of the question. I sincerely believe that the users of SO is not in the business of racism / prejudices and they vote on each question on its merits alone. The OP has shown no attempt to look for an answer / provide existing code they are using, it might be a good...

Comment: question, but it is a poorly formed question / question content.

Comment: it just plain doesn't make a lot of sense, @Script47.  the question just literally could not be more clear, specific and detailed.   it states exactly what is needed, exactly what was done, and exactly what didn't work.  the whole thing is mystifying.  anyway cheers.

Answer (score 15):

While an image is useful for a question that asks "I want to achieve this layout", the lack of actual code appears to indicate that the OP hasn't actually **tried** anything. This is what people are probably reacting to.

A better question would be:

> I'm trying to produce *this* layout and I have *this* code but it's not working as you can see from *this* screenshot.

This gives potential answerers something to work with.

As it stands the question could be read like a request for someone else to write the OP's code for them.

Comment: it's difficult to agree with that , Chris.   the specific answer to this specific, actual, autolayout issue is indeed the answer i supplied.  Regarding youre rewording (using the word "*this*"), the actual question is far better.  it completely explains where he used a constaint etc, what the problem is on what device and so on.

Comment: I mean frankly you're saying "I don't like the OP's writing styl;e as it is not native English".   Sort of the point of this meta.

Comment: No, that's not what Chris is saying here. He's saying that the question smells like a gimmeh teh codez question, and people flagged and voted that way. Rewriting it to make it clear to those reading the question that your interpretation is the correct one is the answer. It's also the best way to get it reopened. Maybe you should edit the question so that it matches the one in your head more closely. Just don't editorialize in the edit, that wouldn't go well...

Comment: @Fattie Rather than describing the problem they're having with *code not shown*, they should have *shown the actual code they were having a problem with*, in addition to describing what their problem with it is, and a screenshot of what they wanted the output to look like.  That you were able to guess enough of what their actual code was to give an answer suitable for them doesn't change the fact that the question is sorely lacking as a result of the fact that readers *had* to guess as to what the author was actually doing.

Comment: "code .. "  "code..."  you don't use code to program a graphical IDE.

Comment: As I explained, I thought at great length in the question here.  No worries though

Comment: "Rewriting it to make it clear to those reading the question that your interpretation is the correct one is the answer. "  fair enough Will, good point

Comment: @Fattie it doesn't have to be code in the traditional sense, but it has to be whatever the OP inputs to get the output.

Comment: so you mean - screen shots of the IDE (constraints etc), rather than just describing them?   I can't really support that idea man.  Anyway cheers.

Comment: @Fattie no I didn't mean more screenshots. I meant text in the question that could be copied.

Comment: In the end doesn't the graphical IDE produce some code? If not, how does it run on the device?